# Como remover botão com um clique usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho o seguinte botão na página:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >
        <div class="">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-raised marginRight10"  id="adicionar" onclick="AddHistorico()"><i class="material-icons">add</i> <span class="marginLeft5">@QJW.Resources.Palavra.ADICIONAR</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Preciso remover ele após o `onclick`:

```
<td class="text-center"> 
   <a class="btn btn-mini btn-raised btn-info margin0" onclick="AlterarHistorico()"> 
       <i class="material-icons">create</i>
   </a>
</td>
```

Dentro desse botão (mostrado acima) tem uma função `AlterarHistorico()` quero colocar a função de remover dentro dela

Tentei dessa forma mas não tenho conhecimento com jQuery

```
    $(".remover").click(function () {
      var adicionar = $(this).attr("adicionar");
     $("#remover" + adicionar).remove();
    });
```

Comment: Pq não usa só $(this).hide() dentro da function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo abaixo, existe o botão chamado exemplo quando clicado nele, o mesmo some.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#btn_teste').click(function() {
    this.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn_teste">exemplo</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Usei a seguinte função do jquery:

//função que adicionou hidden no campo que eu queria que sumisse
$("#adicionar").addClass("hidden")

## adicionar é o atalho para localizar o campo e adicionar o hidden no mesmo